# google code prettify will not show images

Tags: javascript, html, prettify

I followed the instructions fr google preffify and all I get is a box with nonthing in it on the page.  WHere did I go wrong?  I get 200 for the includes.

```
 <link href="static/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>


<body onload="prettyPrint()">


        <pre class="prettyprint"><code class="language-html">
            <img src="http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=tt&google_cm&avid=9000&tag=alaska&campaign_id=8002" /> 
        </code></pre>

        <pre class=prettyprint>
            <img src='http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=tt&google_cm&avid=9000&tag=alaska&campaign_id=8002' /> 
        </pre>


</body>
```

Comment: What exactly did you expect it to "prettify"?  The `<img>` tags?

Comment: I bet you did not include `prettify.js`. What does console say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're expecting the `<img>` tags to be prettified, that's not going to work; the browser is going to interpret them.

Try escaping the `<` etc:

```
&lt;img src="http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=tt&google_cm&avid=9000&tag=alaska&campaign_id=8002" /&gt;
```

*edit* — however, that tool doesn't appear to have an HTML module.

Answer (score 0):

escaping the "<" and ">" will make it work

```
    <pre class="prettyprint"><code class="language-html">
        &lt;img src="http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=tt&google_cm&avid=9000&tag=alaska&campaign_id=8002" /&gt;
    </code></pre>

    <pre class=prettyprint>
        &lt;img src='http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=tt&google_cm&avid=9000&tag=alaska&campaign_id=8002' /&gt;
    </pre>
```